# dynamic linking with LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, dynamic-linking

I want to execute functions in a module, this module will have dependencies resolved in other modules. the modules might change (dynamic compilation environment) so i would prefer not not link all the dependencies in a single monolithic module, that is, if it can be avoided

I hope to use `Linker::linkModules` but this is always destructive on the source module. That is ok for one module depending on a single one, since if that one changed, is no big deal, but isn't it overkill to rebuild and relink N-1 modules that did not change just because of a single one that changed?

I wonder if there is a non-destructive version of linkModules that can work for JIT execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Linker::LinkModules(destinationModule, sourceModule, Linker::PreserveSource, &error);
```

If you pass `Linker::PreserveSource` instead of `Linker::DestroySource`, you can continue to use `sourceModule` after the call.

Answer (score 1):

We have done something similar in the dynamic compilation environment inside our Fabric Engine product (http://fabricengine.com/).  LLVM is not currently very well adapted to this kind of complex "JIT" environment, but we managed to make it work by linking through an extra level of indirection (ie. a double pointer) and then subclassing llvm::MemoryManager to overload llvm::MemoryManager::getPointerToNamedFunction to resolve symbols globally between modules.  By using a double pointer, you can change one module without changing any others.  You have to be slightly careful but it isn't too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible the way you are describing he problem.

In your ideal solution, if modules `A` and `B` were linked, changing `B` would be immediately observable in `A`?

If this is the case I do not believe this to be possible. (try looking at the contents of `A` after linking `B`. The symbols of `B` have been copied into `A`)

If you simply want to perserve the information in `B`, you may copy `B` first with `llvm::CloneModule`, passing the result to `Linker::linkModules`.

Comment: as in normal shared libraries, if `B`changes, `A` would still need to be relinked to the new B. My point is: if A is linked against `B0`, `B1`... `BN` and one of them changes, i should only have to relink the references to that one, since the rest did not change. The current linkModules is working as a static linker (copying everything into the target module)

Comment: The Linux kernel, with its modules, allows something like this (unload a module, reload a new version). But there the process is under the kernel's control, and there are interlocks in place to ensure the code isn't being used.